# How to post/put a LIST of entities/ an EntitySet within Apache Olingo?

Tags: java, rest, odata, olingo

I want to `HTTP-PUT` a list of entities/ entitySet (I guess it is similar for `HTTP-POST`). Below is the body of the query. This query works within Postman.

```
 {
  "value": [
    {
        "@odata.type": "Demo.GridPoint",
        "x": 2.2,
        "y": 1.2
    },
    {
        "@odata.type": "Demo.GridPoint",
        "x": 4,
        "y": 5
    },
    {
        "@odata.type": "Demo.GridPoint",
        "x": 1,
        "y": 9
    }
  ]
}
```

`Demo.GridPoint` is a `ComplexType`

I tried to create a `ClientEntity` and add the different values as a `ComplexProperty`:

```
ClientEntity coordinates = client.getObjectFactory().newEntity(coordinatesFqn);
for(/* all grid Points */){
    coordinates.add(client.getObjectFactory().newComplexProperty("", gridPoint));
}
```

However, the function [`newComplexProperty(String name, ClientComplexValue value)`](https://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata4/org/apache/olingo/client/api/domain/ClientObjectFactory.html#newComplexProperty-java.lang.String-org.apache.olingo.client.api.domain.ClientComplexValue-) requires the `ComplexValue` **and** a name. Hence the query produced does not fit the expected format and fails:

```
{"@odata.type":"Demo.Coordinates",
"":{"@odata.type":"Demo.GridPoint","x@odata.type":"Double","x":2.2,"y@odata.type":"Double","y":1.2},
"":{"@odata.type":"Demo.GridPoint","x@odata.type":"Double","x":4,"y@odata.type":"Double","y":5}
"":{"@odata.type":"Demo.GridPoint","x@odata.type":"Double","x":1,"y@odata.type":"Double","y":9}
}
```

How can one POST/ PUT a list of entities/ an EntitySet?

Answer (score 0):

You could add support for batch requests. They allow you to send several requests in one.

http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/batch-processing/